# How to replace hostname with IP address in a network drive path using batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
set SourceDir=\\my_server\path    

if "%SourceDir:~0,2%"=="\\" (
  set sourceHost= REM not sure what to do. here I need to isolate hostname
  for /f "tokens=2" %%b in ('nslookup %SourceDir%^|find /i "Address"') do set ser_ip=%%b
  REM here I need to replace my_server with %ser_ip%     
)
```

In this code I'm trying to replace the host-name with IP address in a network path.

1. in the `set sourceHost= REM not sure what to do. here I need to isolate hostname` Line I need to isolate the hostname from the path
2. in the `REM here I need to replace my_server with %ser_ip%` line need to  replace host name with retrieved ip address

if the nslookup ip adress is  `10.12.13.14` last result should be `\\10.12.13.14\path`
Please help me for these two lines. Thank you!

Comment: Are you getting the hostname of the pc it's running on, or the hostname of the server? Do you know the name of the server already?

Comment: its host name of the server. Network path pass to the batch file. So I have the hostname as the first part of the path. \\\`my_server`\path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with ping instead of nslookup. If there are IPv6 addresses they are more difficult to parse and ping has a `-4` option.
The ip is easy to extract as it is enclosed in square brackets.:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceDir=\\my_server\path"
if "%SourceDir:~0,2%"=="\\" (
  for /f "delims=\" %%H in ( "%SourceDir%"
  ) Do for /f "tokens=2delims=[]" %%b in ('ping -n 1 -4 %%H^|find "["'
  ) do Set "SourceDir=!SourceDir:%%H=%%b!"
)
Echo %SourceDir%
```

Comment: I choose this answer because of the IPV6 thing @LotPings talks about, though `aschipfi` answer cater for my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

What about this (assuming you want to stick to `nslookup`):

```cmd
set "SourceDir=\\my_server\path"

if "%SourceDir:~0,2%"=="\\" (
  rem // Extract server name and splif off remaining path:
  for /F "tokens=1* delims=\" %%a in ("%SourceDir%") do set "sourceHost=%%a" & set "sourceShare=%%b"
  for /F "tokens=2" %%b in ('nslookup %SourceDir%^|find /I "Address"') do set "ser_ip=%%b"
  rem // Assemble new path by IP and former remaining path:
  echo "\\%ser_ip%\%sourceShare%"
)
```